Является ли сложным предложение?
"Он кинулся спасать, он заслонил собой своё детище".

Является ли сложным предложение?
Да.
Почему?
Тут две грамматические основы:
Он кинулся спасать, он заслонил собой своё детище.
__ _______________  __ ________
   _______________     ________

